# Import data from another sheet using ID but only some columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a google sheet like this :

[image: example1]

And another one like this :

[image: example2]

I want in the second google sheet to pull data from the first sheet that matches those IDs
I have tried index & match, vlookup, lookup but none of them got me to my point especially with using importrange to pull data from the second file I couldn't solve my 
Thanks in advance for your help

This is where I am trying to make the magic happen if you are wondering :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TZYo641Av4SHaHLjSPuAZv3DSnVw0pqSubbtsiYw8Uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Mother!B:B, Mother!A:A, Mother!C:D}, {2,3,4}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]